# How do I handle errors for fs.createReadStream() in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built a simple server that handled errors (files that aren't found, for example) which works fine:

```
    fs.readFile(fullPath, function(err, data) {

        // If there is an error, return 404
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
            debug.log("File denied: " + fullPath);
        } else {
            var length      = data.length;
            var extension   = getExtension(path);
            var type        = getType(extension);

            // If the type doesn't match a MIME type that this app serves, return 404
            if (!type) {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.end();
                debug.log("File denied: " + fullPath);

            // Otherwise, serve the file
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Length' : length,
                    'Content-Type' : type
                });
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
                debug.log("File served: " + fullPath);
            }
        }
    });
```

But I decided that I want to support compression, so I need to use `fs.createReadStream()` to read the file, like in this example that I'm looking at:

```
//Check request headers
var acceptEncoding = req.headers['accept-encoding'];
if (!acceptEncoding) {
    acceptEncoding = '';
}

var raw = fs.createReadStream(fullPath);

// Note: this is not a conformant accept-encoding parser.
// See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3
if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bdeflate\b/)) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'deflate' });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createDeflate()).pipe(response);
} else if (acceptEncoding.match(/\bgzip\b/)) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-encoding': 'gzip' });
    raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(response);
} else {
    response.writeHead(200, {});
    raw.pipe(response);
}
```

So my problem is that I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate my error handling into the stream approach since `fs.createReadStream()` doesn't take a callback function.

**How do I handle errors for Node.js fs.createReadStream()?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Streams can emit an `error` event. You can listen for this event to prevent the default behavior of throwing the error:

```
raw.on('error', function(err) {
  // do something with `err`
});
```

Comment: Cool, I was thinking of something like that but didn't see it in the docs.

Comment: [Here](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error) is the link to the readable stream error event doc.