# How to prevent StreamableFile / createReadStream to leak path in NestJS

Tags: node.js, stream, nestjs

**What I try to do**
I want to stream the content of a file to a http client using NestJs.
At the moment I use the `StreamableFile` Object as stated [in the NestJs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files#streamable-file-class)

**The problem**
When the file on the server is not found

- my solution sends a `400 Bad Request` instead of 404
- more importantly, the message of the **error contains the path to the server side file**

Unfortunately I don't see yet how I can catch the error before it is sent to the client.

The endpoint in my NestJs Controller

```
@Get('coordinates/:processId')
@Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
public async getCoordinates(
    @Param('processId') processId: string
): Promise<StreamableFile> {
    
    return this.getFileContentStream(
        join(
            this.getProcessingDir(processId),
            "coordinates.json"
        )
    );
}
```

And my `getFileContentStream` method to do what is necessary

```
private getFileContentStream(path: string): Promise<StreamableFile> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        // throw new BadRequestException("test");

        const errorHandler = (err: Error) => {
            const myErr = new Error(`Error reading data`, { cause: err });
            Logger.error(getErrorMessageWithCausedByParts(myErr));
            reject(myErr);
        }
    
        const stream = createReadStream(path);
            
        stream.on('error', errorHandler);
        // stream.prependListener('error', errorHandler)
        //stream.on('end', () => Logger.verbose(`End of streaming '${path}'`));

        resolve(new StreamableFile(stream))
    })
}
```

And here is the error log

```
[Nest] 262768  - 16.08.2023, 21:12:16   ERROR Error: Error reading data
    at ReadStream.errorHandler (...\src\lib\controllers\fem-results.controller.ts:40:31)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[caused by] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\processing\04921742-c563-4a2d-96d1-ef8786daf014\info.json'
[Nest] 262768  - 16.08.2023, 21:12:16   DEBUG GET /api/calc/fem-results/info/04921742-c563-4a2d-96d1-ef8786daf014 400 193 - 239.489 ms
[Nest] 262768  - 16.08.2023, 21:12:16   ERROR [ExpressAdapter] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\processing\04921742-c563-4a2d-96d1-ef8786daf014\info.json'
```

The error in the last line is also sent to the client. The path to the file is absolute. I just shortened it with ...

I read *"you can listen for this event to prevent the default behavior of throwing the error"* in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27640174/7869582) and also [this](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv/issues/155#issuecomment-36191678) looks like I can filter it but either I do it wrong or that's not true for when the stream is used with StreamableFile.

I don't know when the ReadStream tries to access the file but I guess it is only after resolving the promise, so rejecting will probably not work. But I am sure there is some way to prevent that error text from leaking to the client.

Do I have to use some way of piping to filter out that error or do you know another way of doing this?